# Custom cost function in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to custom my cost function in tensorflow.
However, I want to access to every elements of the tensor `y_pred`.
To do that, I convert `y_pred` into numpy array.
After I do calculation, I convert back to the tensor
But when I run my code, it has an error as

> ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['dense/kernel:0',
> 'dense/bias:0', 'dense_1/kernel:0', 'dense_1/bias:0',
> 'dense_2/kernel:0', 'dense_2/bias:0', 'dense_3/kernel:0',
> 'dense_3/bias:0'].

This is my code
[here y_true and y_pred have shape of (,8)]

```
def custom_loss_function(y_true, y_pred):
    y_pred_arr = y_pred.numpy()
    for i in range(len(y_pred_arr)):
        a = y_pred.numpy()[i,0]
        b = y_pred.numpy()[i,1]
        c = y_pred.numpy()[i,2]
        d = y_pred.numpy()[i,3]
        e = y_pred.numpy()[i,4]
        f = y_pred.numpy()[i,5]
        g = y_pred.numpy()[i,6]
        h = y_pred.numpy()[i,7]
  
        T = tf.Variable(np.zeros(shape=[8]))
        MSM = a**2+b**2+c**2+d**2+e**2+f**2+g**2+h**2
        T = T[0].assign((a**2+b**2+c**2+d**2)/MSM)
        T = T[1].assign(0.0)
        T = T[2].assign((a*e+b*f+c*g+d*h)/MSM)
        T = T[3].assign((-a*f+b*e-c*h+d*g)/MSM)
        T = T[4].assign((e*a+f*b+g*c+h*d)/MSM)
        T = T[5].assign((-e*b+f*a-g*d+h*c)/MSM)
        T = T[6].assign((e**2+f**2+g**2+h**2)/MSM)
        T = T[7].assign(0.0)

        for j in range (0,7):
            y_pred_arr[i,j] = T[j]

    y_pred_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_pred_arr,dtype=tf.float32)
    return tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred_tensor)
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You gave an error and some code, but you didn't state a question.

Comment: The reason of no gradients because you convert the tensor to numpy array inside the loss function which break the tensor flow dependency, don't do that!

Comment: @Mr.ForExample is 100% right. There is no path between your tf.variable and cost tensor that you are trying to minimize due to your numpy conversion